# Power and Visual Advice Neeed

Tags: power, hdmi, amazon

I am VERY new to the aspect of using a Raspberry Pi for projects and I want to make my first project something to remember. So I am making an emulator with a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B and have yet to actually buy the parts. I just need some help with the power and visual aspects of this. Can someone recommend me or give me a link (preferably on Amazon) of a 3.5" HDMI monitor that needs no prior driver installation? Everywhere I go to find a monitor, someone is talking about driver installation so, I may not even need to worry about that. Also, what should I use portably power a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B and a HDMI monitor?

Comment: Shopping recommendations are explicitly off-topic per the site's FAQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's an HDMI monitor, then it's per definition driver-less. Other displays for the Pi aren't driver-less, except for the official 7" touch display.

For the power supply, just follow the official Fondation 2.5A supply to be on the date dose until you've gained more experience.